# deprecated errors while installing packagesin gastby

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, gatsby

I am using a Gatsby theme and facing this errors while installing packages ,
I've tried `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`  
but when I run `gatsby develop`  I get the errors again :
this is the errors I am facing :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-owl-carousel3@2.2.5
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"15.x || 16.x || 17.x" from @gatsbyjs/reach-router@1.3.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@gatsbyjs/reach-router
npm ERR!     @gatsbyjs/reach-router@"^1.3.6" from gatsby@4.6.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!       gatsby@"^4.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       12 more (babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries, ...)
npm ERR!     peer @gatsbyjs/reach-router@"^1.3.5" from gatsby-link@4.6.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/gatsby-link
npm ERR!       gatsby-link@"^4.6.0" from gatsby@4.6.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!         gatsby@"^4.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!         12 more (babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries, ...)
npm ERR!     1 more (gatsby-react-router-scroll)
npm ERR!   18 more (@loadable/component, gatsby, gatsby-link, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-owl-carousel3@2.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-owl-carousel3
npm ERR!   react-owl-carousel3@"^2.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-owl-carousel3@2.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-owl-carousel3
npm ERR!     react-owl-carousel3@"^2.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\foxxp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\foxxp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-04T23_14_25_607Z-debug-0.log
```

It seems there lot of deprecated versions
How Can i fix this please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

- Remove your `node_modules`
- Install the (peer) dependencies again with:

  ```
  npm install --legacy-peer-deps
  ```
- Start the development process again with:

  ```
  gatsby develop
  ```

If the issue persists remove your `package-lock.json` file and redo all the processes above.